Having trouble with webcam - does not display
I have troulbe with my camera display (on Lenovo Ideapad elemental 14 intel i7 1255u), that I cannot joint vedio conference, the webcam isn't displaying.
I run a couple of test and compare with my system specification. My system specification (from the website of manufacturer) is:
               Display  
1920x1080 FullHD 14" IPS Matte display
16:9 Aspect Ratio

I do not know what happens, but this seems to be changed, and I cant get it set back.
$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 190mm
   2880x1800    119.96*+
   2048x1536    119.95  
   1920x1440    119.97  
   1600x1200    119.82  
   1440x1080    119.92  
   1400x1050    119.90  
   1280x1024    119.83  
   1280x960     119.89  
   1152x864     119.77  
   1024x768     119.80  
   800x600      119.85  
   640x480      119.52  
   320x240      117.34  
   2560x1600    119.93  
   1920x1200    119.90  
   1680x1050    119.89  
   1920x1080    119.93
   .......       ..  
   640x350      119.24  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96

Further..
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23

$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20

$ xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
$ 


Seems like this mode is added, so:
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23


How do I reset the display to its original resolution 1920x1080`?
EDIT
Revert to the default settings by:
sudo systemctl restart gdm  #GNOME

System reboots and on resume, no change:
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


edit-2
The camera seems to be detected, as far:
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 30c9:00c2 Luxvisions Innotech Limited Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


edit-3:
I do not seem to proceed with the commands as far the answer.
$ xrandr --rmmode "1920x1080_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  17 (RRDestroyMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40

Even though I generated the modeline, like so:
$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  39

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 301mm x 188mm
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96 +
   2880x1800    120.00*+  60.00 +
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1600     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00    
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00
   ....           ..  
   320x175       60.00  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

edit-4
Running the python code from the link in @kanehekili's comment:
$ python find-camera.py 
Name: Integrated RGB Camera: Integrat
PORT: /dev/video0
Buffertypes: [<V4l2BufferType.VIDEO_CAPTURE: 1>]
>> buf: V4l2Format(format=MJPEG, description=Motion-JPEG, flags=1)
>> buf: V4l2Format(format=YUYV, description=YUYV 4:2:2, flags=0)
Found port: 0  is intern: True
Name: Integrated RGB Camera: Integrat
PORT: /dev/video2
Buffertypes: [<V4l2BufferType.VIDEO_CAPTURE: 1>]
>> buf: V4l2Format(format=GREY, description=8-bit Greyscale, flags=0)
Found port: 2  is intern: True


For this, I cannot join video meeting: zoom, jitsi, google etc.
NOTE; This answer didn't solve my problem.
edit-5:
I generated a snapshot of my computer's hardware state, like so:
$ sudo -E hw-probe -all -upload
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
Probe for hardware ... Ok
Reading logs ... Ok
Uploaded to DB, Thank you!

Probe uploaded here.
Looks like there's a problem with the graphic's card, screenshot below.

EDIT-6:-
Additional details about hardware configurations:
$ sudo dmidecode -t system
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.6 present.
# SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.5.0 are not
# fully supported by this version of dmidecode.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 83D2
        Version: IdeaPad Pro 5 14IMH9
        Serial Number: YX0ATZKL
        UUID: 20240515-1893-41d8-4294-189341d84298
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_83D2_BU_idea_FM_IdeaPad Pro 5 14IMH9
        Family: IdeaPad Pro 5 14IMH9

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
        Option 1: ConfigOptions1
        Option 2: ConfigOptions2
        Option 3: ConfigOptions3

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 15, 29 bytes
System Event Log
        Area Length: 0 bytes
        Header Start Offset: 0x0000
        Header Length: 8192 bytes
        Data Start Offset: 0x2000
        Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
        Access Address: 0x0000
        Status: Valid, Not Full
        Change Token: 0x12345678
        Header Format: OEM-specific
        Supported Log Type Descriptors: 3
        Descriptor 1: POST memory resize
        Data Format 1: None
        Descriptor 2: POST error
        Data Format 2: POST results bitmap
        Descriptor 3: Log area reset/cleared
        Data Format 3: None

Handle 0x0040, DMI type 32, 11 bytes
System Boot Information
        Status: No errors detected

2.hostnamectl:
$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: xxx
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop 
      Machine ID: b34a9da73cdd44509d21eafcb53c3e19
         Boot ID: e512c7125b5241aab65344876dcdf0e0
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS              
          Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-49-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: IdeaPad Pro 5 14IMH9
Firmware Version: N8CN25WW
   Firmware Date: Wed 2024-03-13
    Firmware Age: 8month 4w 1d

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


xrandr should not be the problem, lsusb might tell us more. Usually the internal camera is connected to the usb bus. Maybe some driver is missing

the webcam seems detected, as far my recent edit.

Check here, but might work. (ID is USB 30c9:003a, so a little bit different from yours).  Check my code for finding a camera - remove the cv2 import and associated code

@kanehekili can you please explain further how to use the resource in the first link of your comment?

@kanehekili I added the output of the python code from repo. in edit-4. can you explain what the output means?

It found 2 Cameras: Port 0 (which has a mjpeg format) and one on Port2 (which is a black and white format). The output shows that your cameras are detected. /dev/video0 is the device you need and it should work

@kanehekili ah, I see. so how do I proceed to fix this?

I am not sure how to use the "ID is USB 30c9:003a" you shared with in in the https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:30c9-003a
Is it a driver to install, and how?

There are multiple problems with this question. You don't give enough info (e.g. what Ubuntu version?) You give conflicting and incorrect info (e.g. what model of Lenovo; there's no such thing as an "Ideapad Elemental" that I can see and a model number is more important than a CPU type.) But mostly, you are asking 2 questions. Split this into 2 different questions: [1] Screen resolution and [2] webcam issues. Provide much more info for both.

@LiamProven  I thought the webcam wasn't displaying video in videoconferencing because of screen resolution problem. I give further details regarding the things  you noted in question edit-6.

@AminaUmar OK, then -- there are 3 problems with the question. Add: [3] you seem to be guessing at interactions.

@LiamProven okay

There is no problem with having two cameras. Just tell you apps to use the correct one. This problem is not a XServer/xrandr problem. So I concur with Kim.

Why are you messing with xrandr if you have a camera issue?
Reset and reconfigure the display settings and set up your camera using the following steps:

Remove existing custom modes:
xrandr --rmmode "1920x1080_60.00"


Generate modeline:
cvt 1920 1080 60


Create and apply new mode:
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"


Check camera module:
lsmod | grep uvcvideo


Load camera module if its not listed:
sudo modprobe uvcvideo


Test camera:
v4l2-ctl --list-devices


Check permissions:
ls -l /dev/video*


Add user to video group  :
sudo usermod -a -G video $USER


Install extra modules if needed:
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)


Reboot:
sudo reboot


Test with Cheese:
sudo apt install cheese
cheese




Thank you for your answer. I could not proceed with commands the answer, as far my edit-3. Do you why the generated modeline could not be enabled after reset.

Information Gathering is in Order Here
XRandR is telling you that the 1920x1080 resolution is not supported by either the driver your using or the hardware itself. As such, one cannot force a modeline to run that isn't supported either.  If one is certain that 1920x1080 is a supported resolution, we need to verify that with two independent tools that aren't XRandR

Read the EDID:

Add the Universal Repository: sudo add-apt-repository universe
Install the Read EDID package: sudo apt install read-edid
Extract the EDID blob to a file: get-edid > edidinfo
Parse the EDID blob: parse-edid < edidinfo


Verify your Graphics Card can match the maximum output reported in step 1.

Use a tool like lspci to find the Graphics Card Name: lspci | grep vga



From Googling myself, and as a hunch, I'm assuming that the Graphics card is a  Intel UHD xxxx
Camera vs Monitor
The integrated webcam cannot go above the maximum resolution of the Graphics Card.  Trying to force it to do so can cause damage.  Set the monitor to the maximum resolution found above and then activate the camera.

The camera app on 24.04 is not enabled by default. I believe this terminal command will enable it.  sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire.service - OR - sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service ---- As an alternative install the 'Cheese' camera app. It has a few more features than the default camera app. Command= sudo apt-get install cheese - Either way this should get you sorted out. As far as restoring display resolution - open 'Settings' - 'Displays' and from that menu you can choose your display resolution. Camera resolution is usually set in the camera app preferences. Hope this works.

I've done everything I can find, Ubuntu 24.04, Lenovo T490, Lsusb sees the cam, added myself to the user group.
:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7250 Huasheng Electronics USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera (1280x720@30)

:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-8):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/media0

:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Dec 20 14:51 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Dec 20 14:51 /dev/video1

but when I run sudo systemctl, I get "no medium found"?
$ sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found

